# Formal proof of the statement

Tags: first-order-logic

Given two formulae $\varphi $ and $\varphi '$, how does one formally prove the following statement?

$$\forall x (\varphi (x)\wedge \varphi'(x))\equiv \forall y \varphi (y)\wedge \forall z \varphi'(z)$$

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this up to your standards of rigor, but here's how I'd do it.

*Remark*. If you truly want a "formal proof," you'll need to specify what deductive system you're working in. Anyway, what follows is what I'd call a "rigorous, informal proof."

$(\Longrightarrow)$ Suppose $\forall x[\phi(x) \wedge \phi'(x)].$

> Let $x$ be arbitrary.
>
> ---
>
> Then $\phi(x) \wedge \phi'(x)$.
>
> Thus $\phi(x)$, and also $\phi'(x)$.

Since we have shown $\phi(x)$ under the assumption that $x$ is arbitrary, we may conclude $\forall x \phi(x)$. Similarly, we may conclude $\forall x \phi'(x)$. Thus

$$\forall x \phi(x) \wedge \forall x \phi'(x)$$

as required.

$(\Longleftarrow)$ Suppose $\forall x \phi(x) \wedge \forall x \phi'(x)$. Thus

$$[1] \quad \forall x \phi(x)$$

$$[2] \quad \forall x \phi'(x)$$

> Let $x$ be arbitrary.
>
> ---
>
> Then by [1], we have $\phi(x)$.
>
> And by [2], we have $\phi'(x)$.
>
> Thus $\phi(x) \wedge \phi'(x)$.

Since we have shown $\phi(x) \wedge \phi'(x)$ under the assumption that $x$ is arbitrary, we may conclude that $$\forall x[\phi(x) \wedge \phi'(x)]$$
as required.